# Physical motivation for tight/overtwisted dichotomy

Tags: differential-geometry, contact-topology

I'm learning about tight vs. overtwisted contact structures in contact geometry. Is there any particular reason why we care about the existence/nonexistence of overtwisted disks in a contact structure? I know contact geometry has a lot of applications to physics, so I'm curious to know if there are any big physical reasons for why we care about this distinction.